# Very slow wireless connection

Tags: wireless

I'm very naive to the ways of Ubuntu.  My problem is that no matter which release i use, my wifi connection is very slow (can't stream anything, pages load slowly, etc.).   However, when plugged into the router the speed is very fast/as it should be.

```
brandt@Brandtsys:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for brandt: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: f0:de:f1:71:62:57
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: cc:af:78:68:28:7c
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.67 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 memory:f0100000-f010ffff
brandt@Brandtsys:~$
```

Details: OS Ubuntu 13.10
         Memory 5.3 GiB
         Processor AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 
         Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO
         OS Type 64-bit
         Disk 732.5 GB

I have scoured google and searches

http://pastebin.com/nQJKe0hR

Comment: May be to do with your graphics adapter, and its drivers, if you have one please list it, and as many details as possible.

Comment: not sure if above edit is what you meant. if not, is there a cmd i can use to get the exact info that might help?

Comment: after entering first cmd it returned as "sudo aptitude install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
sudo: aptitude: command not found".  Also, on cmd #2 how do i know what my windows driver is ("your driver")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windows drivers yo solve your problem:

Install ndiswrapper

```
sudo install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Install the WiFi driver (from Windows):

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i yourdriver.inf
```

Check the driver is working:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -l
```

Load the module:

```
sudo depmod -a

sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Configure modprobe so that it loads ndiswrapper:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

Edit the modules to add ndiswrapper at the end:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Remember to add ndiswrapper at the end.

Hope you now have your WiFi back to max speed!

Comment: Thank you for your help: First cmd returns "sudo: aptitude: command not found". Also, on cmd #2 how do i know what my windows driver is ("your driver")?

Comment: Your windows driver you must go to the support page of your computer download it and get the inf file, take out aptitude sorry.

Comment: No idea why this had a -1 score. This is almost exactly what I did and it worked. You do have to supply the *.inf file (and possibly the corresponding *.sys file in the same directory).

Answer (score 0):

Try getting inside the router configuration page (usually 192.168.1.1 in any browser such as Firefox) and entering the username and password as router administrator. Once in, then change the frequency channel / network channel. Most of the time changing channel solves speed issues.